# маршрутизация между клиентами ovpn

Tags: windows, openvpn

настроен сервер ovpn на windows. одна подсеть. client-to-client отключен. клиенты видят сервер и не видят друг друга.
Подскажите пожалуйтса, как настроить:

1. чтобы только определенные клиенты могли видеть определенного клиента
2. чтобы только определенные клиенты могли видеть Всех клиентов